# QGIS for Mac does not show results on identify panel

Tags: qgis-3, mac

I have found a new problem in QGIS 3.2.2 for Mac. When you try to use identify features on any object on the map you do not get any results on identify results panel.

Am I missing something?

I am using QGIS 3.2.2-1, Python 3.6.6 and OS X 10.11.6

Comment: Are you selecting the layer that you try to identify?

Comment: Yes ImanolUr. No success.

Comment: Are you using a database table as the layer in QGIS? This can happen if you've changed the schema of the table.